# Empty folder named '1' created when ArcMap opens

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5

Over the past few days I have noticed a Folder named `1` on my Windows desktop (Windows 10 Home).  I delete it every time I see it, then notice it again a few hours later.

I kept a close eye on my desktop to try to catch when it appeared (I thought maybe it was a virus) and discovered that it appeared as ArcMap finished loading - the splash screen disappears and the ArcMap window appears at the same time the `1` folder appears.

No folder icon on my desktop while ArcMap is opening:
[image]

ArcMap is now open and a new folder has appeared on my desktop:
[image]

What is causing ArcMap to create this new folder on my desktop, and how do I stop it?  I have been using ArcMap for years and have never seen this before.

Comment: Thanks for this. I started noticing the empty 1 folder showing up when I got a new computer. Somewhere in downloading 10.5, something changed from the configuration on my old machine. I hope your solution works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I was writing the question I continued to search, and came across [this old post on Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/151277) which suggested looking in the AdvancedArcMapSettings utility, which can be found in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\Utilities
```

On the *System Paths* tab, the path for *Templates Path* was set to just `1` rather than an actual path.

[image]

Clicking on *Reset all values to default* restored the correct path

[image]

Clicked *Apply* and closed the utility and reopened ArcMap.  Sure enough the `1` folder didn't re-create.

Note: The utility needs to be run with ArcMap closed, and I had to Run as Administrator in order to save the changes.

The Geonet post also indicated that the folder would be created wherever the map document was created.  So I took a look in other folders that I'd used MXDs in, and found a `1` in my working folder `D:\GIS\SE` as well.

I still don't know why it happened, but at least I've found how/where and been able to fix it.

Comment: I recently, saw this folder named "1" on a site I was working at for a few months.  It seemed to appear around the same time IT had implemented some additional backup and I had not thought to consider ArcGIS Desktop a possible source.  I'm no longer at that site but will let them know about your findings here.